# Fatou's lemma in the case that an interval depends on parameters

Tags: analysis, proof-writing, limsup-and-liminf

Fatou's lemma says that

$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_0^tf_n(s)ds\ge \int_0^t\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n(s)ds
$$

provided that there exists a nonnegative integrable function $g$ such that $f_n\ge-g$ for all $n$.
In addition, if $f_n$ is, for each $n$, lower semicontinuous function, then

$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_0^tf_n(s)ds\ge \int_0^t f(s)ds,
$$ 
where $t>0$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}f_n\ge f$.

I know the above statement.
However, as soon as $t$ depend on the index, i.e., $t_n$, I don't understand.
More precisely, the problem is whether

$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{t_n}f_n(s)ds\ge\int_0^tf(s)ds
$$

is true or not. Here, $\lim t_n=t$.

I tried to apply the above way for $g_n(s):=f_n(s)1_{[0,t_n]}(s)$ but, originally it is not trivial that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}g_n\ge f(s)1_{[0,t]}(s)$ since $f_n$ may be negative. Here $1_{I}$ is the indicator function on $I$.d

I believe that the above inequality holds.
Please any advices, comments or solutions.
Thank you in advance.